# Taking color from another object in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

I'm using the latest version of Adobe Illustrator CC.  I'm on a PC running Win 8.1 with Classic Shell.

How do I copy a color from one object to another?  It's a word, (text converted to path).  I've read a few answers here and on other forums but things were left out... or their method just didn't work for me, or I just couldn't understand what they were saying.

I'm visually impaired, super-dyslexic, and an Aspergers person!!!  So could you be very detailed... and if possible, give me a step by step answer.  I have trouble with things implied.  Talk to me as if I were a 386 PC.

Answer (score 9):

Select the object you want to transfer the color *to*, then click the <kbd>i</kbd> key on your keyboard to access the eyedropper tool. Now click with the eyedropper tool on the object you want to copy the color *from*.

Comment: This copies also other properties such as line width for example. What if I just want color? what is the most efficient way to copy just color?

Comment: One can doubleclick on the pipette tool tp tell what it copies

Answer (score 5):

1. Select the object you want to copy the color to (Target).
2. Select eyedropper tool from toolbar.
3. Click the eyedropper tool on the object from which you intend to copy the color  (Source).

Now you can use the eyedropper tool in three variations to achieve different outcomes:

- Clicking the eyedropper tool on the Source will not only copy the color but also any formatting etc.
- Holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> while clicking the eyedropper on Source will only copy the **Stroke** Color.
- Holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> while clicking the eyedropper on Source will only copy the **Fill** Color.

Hope this helps - Happy Illustrating!